# c# - Pass variable to javascript in a OnClick function - Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, onclick, progress-bar

I have a button and when i click on the button I launch a javascript function (progress bar)

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_tel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClick="btn_telefono" Text="Controlla" CssClass="button" OnClientClick="move()" /></div>
```

Function move():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function move() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
            elem.style.color = "White";
            var width = 0;
            var temp= "<%=intervallo%>";
    var id = setInterval(frame, temp);
    function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            width++;
            elem.style.width = width + '%';
            elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
        }
     }
   }, 0)
 }
 </script>
```

In my code I can set the variable **"intervallo"**.

The code works, but i want to pass the variable **intervallo** when i click on the button.

I tried in several ways but I did not succeed. Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the easiest way is to add a parameter to your function:

```
function move(var x) {
...
}
```

Then, in the page call the method with:

```
...onClientClick="move(x)"
```

Replace x in the method call with the value you want to pass to the function.

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the reply. 

I calculate the variable **intervallo** when I click on the button. 

Then I want to pass on its value. Is not it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where are you trying to pass the variable? To javascript or to the ASP code behind? Perhaps some more code would help.